# Reputation points not attributed

Tags: support, reputation

Sometimes reputation is not awarded correctly. It may be related to being in the task of editing a post when the vote happens (not sure). It happened to me several times, and maybe more than I'm aware. That's not big business the reputation points are lost, but this may hide a broader bug.

[Example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27211/what-is-the-capacity-of-the-vent-surge-tank-in-an-a320). I'm informed of 2 answer upvotes and answer selected:

[image]

But only one vote will ever be counted:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The green check mark of the accepted answer is worth 15 points all on its own.

So you have 1 upvote (10 rep) and the accept (15 rep) for a total of 25 rep.

Comment: Yesss..... I always thought this was +5 for the check mark.

Answer (score 9):

To add on ratchet's answer, you can check [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/3201/mins?tab=reputation&sort=post) page [NOTE: this is mins' page, any user can get its own by checking its own profile]

And from there you see what is happening:

[image]